# What's the name of this insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Here's a picture:

[image]

That's pretty much it, besides that it was found in Vienna, Austria.

Edit: Thanks to Magne Flåten; it's called [Hausmutter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausmutter) in German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a large yellow underwing not finished pumping up its wings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_yellow_underwing